# Alter default binding on a column

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do I alter the "default binding" of a column?

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE [t].[t150806].[tblTest] 
ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint DEFAULT '10' FOR test
```

but since I've set the "default bind" earlier, I wish to continue in this fashion. So how do I set the "default binding" instead`?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter a default constraint - you need to drop the old one:

```
ALTER TABLE [BI011mylovetoys].[mylovetoys150806].[tblTest] 
DROP CONSTRAINT old_constraint
```

and then add your new one:

```
ALTER TABLE [BI011mylovetoys].[mylovetoys150806].[tblTest] 
ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint DEFAULT '10' FOR test
```

Comment: but '10' doesn't show up in the "default binding' field in sql manager when I use this approach. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

A default binding is not the same as a default constraint, as the accepted answer suggests. To alter the default binding of a column, use `sp_unbinddefault` and `sp_binddefault`:

```
CREATE DEFAULT dbo.SYSTEM_DATE AS getdate()
EXECUTE sp_unbindefault N'dbo.tb_company_industry.stamp_modify_date'
GO

EXECUTE sp_bindefault N'dbo.SYSTEM_DATE', N'dbo.tb_company_industry.stamp_modify_date'
GO
```

Though it's worth noting that the documentation for [sp_binddefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177503%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) indicates that the default binding mechanism is deprecated:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. We recommend that you create default definitions by using the DEFAULT keyword of the ALTER TABLE or CREATE TABLE statements instead. For more information, see Creating and Modifying DEFAULT Definitions.